# Getting Unable to set default locale when importing wx

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Getting "Unable to set default locale error: 'unsupported locale setting' "
when importing wx. Just reinstalled Win10 along with eclipse and python and don't understand why I'm getting this error.
Using eclipse 4.20, python 3.9.6, wxPython 4.1.1

Sample code that it's giving me this error

```
import wx

class calc(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Calculator", size=(400,400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        global a
        a = wx.Button(self.panel, label="GO", pos=(100,100), size=(50,50))
        a.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.change, a)

    def change(self,event):
        a.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        self.Refresh()  # for windows
        event.Skip()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = calc()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

thanks for your help

Comment: This works OK for me on Arch - looks like an Eclipse/Win problem not wxPython

Comment: You don't specify what your `locale` is set to. There are threads concerning similar issues on windows. perhaps you could set the locale in the code. Check `wx.Locale()`

Answer (score 1):

NOT a privacy issue! Locale - as in country/language setting.

```
class App(wx.App):
  '''Derive your own App class.'''
  
  def InitLocale(self):
    '''Override with nothing (or impliment local if actually needed)'''
    pass
  #enddef

#endclass

MyApp = App()
MyApp.MainLoop()
```

Python 3.8 on windows broke this for wx.App()

See wxPhonix migration guide:
https://docs.wxpython.org/MigrationGuide.html#possible-locale-mismatch-on-windows

Kevin and Robin are working on it :-) Here is the veryy deeply issue discus https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1616

Robin post SOLUTION: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/apperarence-of-error-popup-each-time-i-run-the-script/35089

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 privacy setting, Location was turned off which prevented apps from accessing location. Turned location ON and issue went away.

Comment: To be fair, the issue didn't go away, you had to allow access to what many might consider a privacy issue. If your code is going to run just on your machine, obviously that isn't a problem. If, however, you want it to run on other peoples machines, you would force them to make a decision, between running your code and keeping MS and others out of their lives.

Comment: Yes, that is true. The code is running just on my PC. Don't like the privacy issues.